# Javascript (preferably Jquery) that will mimic behavior of hashtags

Tags: javascript, jquery, hashtag

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery scroll To Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

Basically, I want my user to be instantly scroll down to a specific anchor tag just like they do with a hashtag. However, I can't use a hashtag and therefore want to scroll them down using javascript (preferably jquery).

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: Take a look at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element

Comment: What? A hashtag is a means of categorising things on Twitter. What does that have to do with scrolling? Do you mean [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) / [anchors](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3)?

Comment: @Quentin, where do you think the idea of hashtags came from?

Comment: @Quentin did you really have trouble understanding what I meant? Was that comment really necessary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will jump instantly to the element matched by `$(selector)`:

```
$(document).scrollTop($(selector).offset().top);
```

If you want a fluid animation:

```
$(document.body).animate({'scrollTop': $(selector).offset().top}, duration);
```